# Calculate time between now() and timestamp field - MySQL or PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a timestamp field named `ending`. I want to calculate the time between now and that.

Here's what I'm trying but result simply says `blob`

```
select item_id, CONCAT(
FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(now(), ending)) / 24), ' days, ',
MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(now(), ending)), 24), ' hours, ',
MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(now(), ending)), ' minutes')
AS TimeDiff from items where item_id=39
```

Or should I use PHP instead? They are both used extensively on the page... I'm working on the assumption that as I'm already doing a query then to include it in that is more efficient than another PHP call - but, I could be wrong!

**UPDATE** I made a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10f3e/2) for this and it works perfectly, so why would my results within MySQL Workbench say `blob`?

This is the table explained:

```
item_id int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
user_id int(11) YES         
title   varchar(128)    YES         
price   decimal(10,2)   YES         
category    int(11) YES         
cat_parent  int(11) YES         
description varchar(1024)   YES         
item_condition  int(11) YES         
delivery    varchar(45) YES         
ending  timestamp   YES         
postcode    varchar(12) YES         
latitude    float(10,6) YES         
longitude   float(10,6) YES         
dateadded   timestamp   YES     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: You need to cast the results of the calculations as strings if you want to use them with other strings.

Comment: Updated question, put wrong query in! Doh!

Comment: Missing closing bracket `CONCAT(...?`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Thanks, fixed OP, that's not the problem, no

Comment: @DarrenSweeney can you add the sql  fiddle with sample data set

Comment: Note that if your DB is set to a time zone that uses daylight savings, a day is _not_ always 24 hours (this is why the recommendation is to set the DB to UTC/GMT).  Does MySQL have leap seconds?

Answer (score 0):

put SELECT at the start of your query?

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(now(), '2012-08-02 11:20')) / 24), ' days, ',
    MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2012-08-05 09:56', '2012-08-02 11:20')), 24), ' hours, ',
    MINUTE(TIMEDIFF('2012-08-05 09:56', '2012-08-02 11:20')), ' minutes, ',
    SECOND(TIMEDIFF('2012-08-05 09:56', '2012-08-02 11:20')), ' seconds')
AS TimeDiff
```

returns
34 days, 22 hours, 36 minutes, 0 seconds

Comment: try using the date function for ending? `DATE(ending)`

Answer (score 0):

You also can use this query -

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, ending, NOW()), ' days ',
    TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(TIME(NOW()), TIME(ending)), '%k hours %i minutes')
  ) TimeDiff
FROM items;
```

About the BLOB type - that is because of different data types values which are used in CONCAT function, to avoid this, use CAST or CONVERT functions, e.g. -

```
SELECT
  CAST(
    CONCAT(
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, ending, NOW()), ' days ',
      TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(TIME(NOW()), TIME(ending)), '%k hours %i minutes')
    ) AS CHAR
  )
  TimeDiff
FROM items;
```